# Set a variable equal to null if it is not included in an array?

Tags: javascript

If I have something like,

```
const {
  someProperty,
  anotherProperty,
  thirdProperty
} = someObject;

const includeProperties = ['someProperty', 'thirdProperty']
```

Is it possible to make `anotherProperty = null`?

Comment: Don't make it const, then you can set

Comment: I want to destructure first, and then conditional set a value to null if it doesn't exist in `includeProperties`

Comment: const {
  someProperty,
  anotherProperty,
  thirdProperty
} = someObject;

By this, you are trying to declare those variables right?

Comment: Yes, first declare and then nullify if needed.

Comment: Have you solved your problem or still looking for some better options?

Answer (score 2):

You may nullify all the not needed properties within source object shallow copy and destructure that:

```js
const srcObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3},
      neededKeys = ['a','b'],
      objCopy = (obj =>
        (Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
          !neededKeys.includes(key) && (obj[key]=null)), obj)
      )({...srcObj}),
      {a,b,c} = objCopy
      
console.log(a,b,c)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Property `c` in `obj` would exist in the case of the question.

Comment: @MikeK : considering your use case, that would be easier to nullify unwanted props before destructuring

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let properties = [
  'someProperty',
  'anotherProperty',
  'thirdProperty'
]

const includeProperties = ['someProperty', 'thirdProperty'];

let object = properties.reduce((acc, val) => {

  if (includeProperties.indexOf(val) === -1) 
    acc[val] = null;
  else 
    acc[val] = 'some value';
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let someProperty = someObject,
       anotherProperty = someObject,
       thirdProperty = someObject;

    const includeProperties = [someProperty, thirdProperty];

if (!includeProperties.include(someVariable))
    someVariable= null;
}
```

This is a possible way to do what you asked.

Comment: Is this what you expected?

Comment: But this is not dynamic in any way. I might not know the properties to nullify.

Comment: Do you want to nullify the variable if it is not in array?